# Composite Query in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a solr schema of something like the following:

```
    `<field type="string" name="id"></field>`
    `<field type="int" name="version"></field>`
    `<field type="string" name="foreignId"></field>`
```

I have the following parameters using to get a result set from the solr core:

q:foreignId={SomeId}

Note that there may be more than one document (and is very likely) that contain the same foreign id, but differing id's. Also, it is possible for multiple documents with the same foreign id, to have the same id, but differing versions.

My problem is, I need to query for ONLY the HIGHEST VERSION of each id, for a foreign id.

For example, with documents (mind my short hand):

id:1
version:1
foreignid:1337

id:1
version:2
foreignId:1337

id:2
version:1
foreignId:9999

I want to query for foreign ids 1337 AND 9999, but only receive two results:

id:1
version:2
foreignId:1337

id:2
version:1
foreignId:9999

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What is probably need is Grouping on Multiple Fields and Sort feature for inner group be able to return a single version for max one, which is currently not supported in Solr.

Comment: This seems to be the case! If you want, find a link supporting it, and add as an answer, and I will mark it correct :)

Comment: added an answer with the JIRA number for grouping on multiple fields, You can vote for it to be included in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Max function` to get only the max of the id like:

```
max(version,0)
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#max

Comment: I have thought of doing such, but seems to not work... Example parameters:

q=id:testid&q=max(version)
still results in multiple documents returned (all have the same id, but differing versions)

Similarly I have the use case of:

q=id:testid1 OR id:testid2&q=max(version)

Which I would like to return me 2 documents. One being the largest version of testid1, and one being the largest version of testid2.

Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

What is probably need is Grouping on Multiple Fields (Check [SOLR-2526](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2526)) and Sort feature for inner group be able to return a single version for max one, which is currently not supported in Solr.

Comment: Can you help me to resolve my problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246715/when-i-do-query-from-solr-it-occurred-a-common-exception-telling-me-that-undefi Thank you!