# When I do query from solr, it occurred a common exception telling me that undefined field userId

Tags: java, solr

I am developing a web application.
 I use spring mvc framework , cassandra and solr.
 I use standalone solr, not solr cloud.
 I use solr as a fulltext retrieval tool.
 I am facing a strange problem, first here is the `schema.xml`.

```
<schema name="KSP_core" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />  
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="text_ik" class="solr.TextField"> 
    <analyzer type="index" isMaxWordLength="true" class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKAnalyzer"/> 
    <analyzer type="query" isMaxWordLength="true" class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKAnalyzer"/> 
    </fieldType>
  </types>

 <fields>   
  <!-- general -->
  <field name="id"        type="uuid"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" required="true"/>
  <field name="dbTable"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="userId"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="originatorId"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
  <field name="associatedObjectId"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="createTime"      type="date"      indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
  <field name="status"     type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
  <field name="postType"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 

  <!-- user activity -->
  <field name="userOperate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>


  <!--user reputation-->
  <field name="reputation" type="int"      indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
  <field name="dayTime"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/> 
  <field name="reason"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 

  <!--user tags-->
  <field name="tagId"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="tagName"      type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 

  <field name="reputationOnTag" type="int"      indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 </fields>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>userId</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

Then I show you the solrconfig.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
 This is a stripped down config file used for a simple example...  
 It is *not* a good example to work from. 
-->
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_40</luceneMatchVersion>
  <!--  The DirectoryFactory to use for indexes.
        solr.StandardDirectoryFactory, the default, is filesystem based.
        solr.RAMDirectoryFactory is memory based, not persistent, and doesn't work with replication. -->
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}"/>

  <dataDir>${solr.core0.data.dir:}</dataDir>

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.core0.data.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>
  </updateHandler>

  <!-- realtime get handler, guaranteed to return the latest stored fields 
    of any document, without the need to commit or open a new searcher. The current 
    implementation relies on the updateLog feature being enabled. -->
  <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>  

  <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" startup="lazy" /> 

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true" />
  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" startup="lazy" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler"  />
  <requestHandler name="/admin/" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers" />

  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- config for the admin interface --> 
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>solr</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

When I query the data from solr, I use the solrj library to achieve the query in general.
 like:

```
   String queryExpression = "*:*";
   String sortField = "createTime";
   String baseUrl = SolrUtil.getSolrBaseURL(solrHttpServer.getBaseURL());
   solrHttpServer.setBaseURL(baseUrl + "/" + coreName);
   SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
   query.setQuery(queryExpression);
   query.setSortField(sortField, SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);
   QueryResponse rsp = solrHttpServer.query(query);
```

And the following code is the error information during the query:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field userId
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:401)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.solr.dao.impl.SolrBaseDaoImpl.query(SolrBaseDaoImpl.java:141)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.service.impl.TagStatsServiceImpl.getUserTagStats(TagStatsServiceImpl.java:50)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.controller.TagStatsController.getUserTagStats(TagStatsController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.augmentum.iaphelper.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.filter.I18nFilter.doFilter(I18nFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

From the information, I just know that my controller, service and dao works normally. 
What is very strange that it works normally in the most of time , but the error must be occurred within 20 times I refresh the JSP page, which made me worried.
I can guarantee that my solr server startup normally.
And index has been loaded. 
I do not know how to find the way to solve it, because I do not know the source of the problem.

In addition, there is many same errors was occurred like following, this time is not the field called userId but the field called dbTable.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field dbTable
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:401)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.solr.dao.impl.SolrBaseDaoImpl.query(SolrBaseDaoImpl.java:135)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.listUserReputationByTime(UserServiceImpl.java:1222)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.controller.UserControler.listUserReputationByTime(UserControler.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.augmentum.iaphelper.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.augmentum.ksp.filter.I18nFilter.doFilter(I18nFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Did anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: I have edited the post.I use standalone solr.

Comment: well looks weird... did you try to query the solr server without using jsp stuff? and will this thing occur again when you are not jsp in that case?

Comment: You have that small excerpt of java code, there I see that you sort by the field `createTime` that you do not declare in your schema, how does that work? Secondly I can see that your client code tries to address a different core that is given in from the outside, do they all have the same schema.xml?

Comment: oh,what i want to express is that the problem is common in my application.now I have edited the question and put the another schema.xml.

Comment: I use different core. And every core have their own schema.xml

Comment: What version of Solr are you using? I can assume that it is 4.0 as you are using the LUCENE_40 codec, but it would be good to know for certain.  

If that's possible, can you update to the 4.5 Solr as well as luceneMatchVersion to  `<luceneMatchVersion>4.5</luceneMatchVersion>`?


`And every core have their own schema.xml`
Make sure you really have that field in the relevant core(I know, I know, but maybe your code queries multiple cores at the same page, and you searching for the problem in the different core).

Comment: yes, i am using solr 4.0.you are right, i queriy multiple cores at the same page.

Comment: but if i upgrade to 4.5, may be the problem will be resolved, but the source of the problem is still unknown.

Comment: You are posting the client side stacktrace, probably posting also the exception logged INSIDE solr could help

Comment: I see that the last caller in the stacktrace is  org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:401), and looking through the source code for HttpSolrServer.java, it throws that exception when the web server doesn't return an OK (SC_OK) status.  Which means that either (a) your client really isn't sending what you think it is, or (b) something very funky is going on on the server.  My money would be on the former.  So, can you dump out the content of the query for debugging before you dispatch it off to the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see, you change baseUrl in your code. As you said in comments, you query multiple cores at the same page, and all of them use the same `HttpSolrServer`. So it seems to be a lack of synchronization in your solution, and that there could be two requests running at the same time, and one request quering the ‘core’ of another.

Of course, you could synchronize your method. But I think, that in your case it is better not to twitch `HttpSolrServer` each time, but to set additional parameter to your query, that will be used as additional path to your `baseUrl`. You will need to set `baseUrl` for `HttpSolrServer` once at creation time:

```
HttpSolrServer solrHttpServer = new HttpSolrServer(baseUrl);
```

and instead of changing it for each query you will set parameter (diff for your code):

```
 String queryExpression = "*:*";
 String sortField = "createTime";
-String baseUrl = SolrUtil.getSolrBaseURL(solrHttpServer.getBaseURL());
-solrHttpServer.setBaseURL(baseUrl + "/" + coreName);
 SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
+query.set(CommonParams.QT, "/" + coreName + "/select");
 query.setQuery(queryExpression);
 query.setSortField(sortField, SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);
 QueryResponse rsp = solrHttpServer.query(query);
```

---

But the best solution is to have separate `HttpSolrServer` for each core:

```
Map<String, HttpSolrServer> servers = new HashMap<String, HttpSolrServer>();
servers.put(coreName1, new HttpSolrServer(baseUrl + "/" + coreName1));
...
```

Resulting code changes:

```
 String queryExpression = "*:*";
 String sortField = "createTime";
-String baseUrl = SolrUtil.getSolrBaseURL(solrHttpServer.getBaseURL());
-solrHttpServer.setBaseURL(baseUrl + "/" + coreName);
 SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
 query.setQuery(queryExpression);
 query.setSortField(sortField, SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);
-QueryResponse rsp = solrHttpServer.query(query);
+QueryResponse rsp = servers.get(coreName).query(query);
```

Comment: hi, I change my solrBaseDaoImpl.java file like you say.but i get a new error that : org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Server at http://localhost:8090/solr/KSP_core returned non ok status:404, message:Not Found.

Comment: The error occurred everytime I made a query. the URL is the expected URL. the baserl is http://localhost:8090/solr which is defined in the solr.properties. I use spring mvc , the properties file was loaded in the applicationContext.xml.And the coreName is KSP_core.

Comment: But if I do not change the code like what you said, it can work, but the undefined field exception still occurr rarely.