# How to achieve synchronized thread in the spring MVC using solrj as a client connecting to the tomcat solr

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, solr

guys,
  At first, I show you the part of applicationContext.xml on ingerating HttpServer.
  And I read the construcotr arguments from the solr.properties.

```
<!-- solr configuration-->
   <bean id="solrHttpServer" class="com.augmentum.ksp.solr.server.SolrHttpServer" scope="prototype">
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.url}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.socketTimeOut}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.connTimeOut}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.maxConnDefault}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.maxConnTotal}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.maxRetries}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.allowCompression}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${solr.followRedirects}" />
    </bean>
```

And following is our query method in DAO layer, we have **many methods** in service layer use the "queryCount" method **at the same time.**

```
@Repository
public class SolrBaseDaoImpl implements SolrBaseDao {

    @Autowired
    private SolrHttpServer solrHttpServer;

     @Override
    public synchronized int queryCount(String coreName, String queryExpression, Set<String> filterQuerys)
    throws SolrServerException, IOException {

        if (null == queryExpression || "".equals(queryExpression)) {
            return 0;
        }

        String baseUrl = SolrUtil.getSolrBaseURL(solrHttpServer.getBaseURL());
        solrHttpServer.setBaseURL(baseUrl + "/" + coreName);
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery(queryExpression);
        // set filter query
        if (null != filterQuerys) {
            for (String fq : filterQuerys) {
                query.addFilterQuery(fq);
            }
        }
        query.setStart(0);
        query.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        QueryResponse rsp = solrHttpServer.query(query);
        return rsp.getResults().size();
    }
}
```

Thus, a problem occurred. Reported that "SolrRemoteException:undefined field ***".
We think that the source of the error is that there is a lot of request access the "queryCount" method **at the same time**, thus we add a "synchronized" decorateor to the method, so that the problem nerver occurred any more.
  But, as we all know, when there is a lot of request access the method one by one, which perfom very slowly. That is terrible! 
  Could you tell me your soultion to the problem ? or the error is not caused by the thread synchronization？

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the configuration of the `SolrHttpServer ` on a per-request basis. Either use a prototype based solution (and lookup a fresh server each time when needed) or use a request scoped based solution using a scoped proxy. But still why do you need to change the URL each time? I would find a different way of passing/calling that URL (or maybe rethink the design?!).

Comment: I found a question is like to this, the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246715/when-i-do-query-from-solr-it-occurred-a-common-exception-telling-me-that-undefi

Comment: Using `query.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` will get you all the result documents back from solr. Please try `query.setRows(0);` and return `rsp.getResults().getNumFound();` Might not fully solve your problem but at least this should increase performance.